# Find coordinates to the last place you died

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to find the coordinates to the last place where you died? Are they stocked into a variable or something? With cheats, of course. I want for my imagination.

Comment: It should be indeed possible, since there's an item that points those coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

In Survival, you can use a [Recovery compass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Recovery_Compass). If you don't have one yet, try not to die to the Warden while trying to obtain it…

In player NBT, the field `LastDeathLocation` contains the last death location, which you can get with:

```
/data get entity @s LastDeathLocation
```

The mod [Deathlog](https://github.com/gliscowo/deathlog) gives a more convenient in-game UI for your status right before death (position, inventory, XP, …), but it only records deaths while it is installed.

Or you could just always have F3 or MiniHUD or so open in all dangerous situations and take a screenshot of the death screen.